# Lift => Mass, for a helicopter in a hover; not Lift = Weight?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, aircraft, lift

Background: According to Newtonian mechanics, a helicopter in a stable hover accelerates ('a') a mass of air ('m') downwards to generate a downward force; according to Newtons 2nd law (Force = ma). Then the 'equal & opposite' upward force produces lift.

Simple experiments with drones (quadcopters) on youtube (e.g. ActionbLab) show that a drone exerts the same force on the ground when at rest, and when the quadcopter is hovering just above the ground/scale. See diagram above.

[image]

The velocity of the downwash confirmed that the downward force was a force sufficient to displace a mass of air each second, that was equal to the drone's mass (Lift => Mass); not its weight (not Lift = Weight).  This seemed odd.

Just to be clear, 'Lift => Mass' is defined above, it does not mean 1 N = 1 kg.

Then consider that drones (and helicopters) circulate a mass of air in a hover. The air pushed down with gravity, pushes air up elsewhere against gravity. Gravity is a universal constant here, and does not affect the circulation of the air.

Therefore, the downward force from the rotors is proportional to the mass of air  circulated each second (not the weight of the air circulated). This assertion supports the data from the experiments showing that the downward force only equals the drone's mass, not its weight.

It appears that the drone is floating on a mass of air equal to its own mass.

[image]

Is it correct to conclude that to hover, the drone only needs to exert a force equal to its own mass, not its weight?

I ask as this is contrary to what is taught in the textbooks; that in a hover, lift from the rotors must equal the weight of the drone, not its mass.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Lift can't be equal to mass as they have different units

Comment: How did you calculate the lift?

Comment: Method to calculate lift:  Multiplied the downwash velocity by the rotor's disc area to obtain the volume of air pushed down each second - the downash. (Velocity x Area = Volume). Then multiplied by the air density to obtain the mass of air pushed down each second (Volume x Density = Mass).  Full calculations are on a paper on Researchgate: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333634008_Archimedes_principle_applied_to_helicopters_to_explain_flight

Comment: A suggestion: if you are saying "Lift=mass" doesn't actually mean "lift (force) is equal to mass (mass)", then why even use this way of talking? It makes the question somewhat unclear. It might be better to just say what you mean without saying the thing you don't actually mean.

Comment: Are you using => to mean "greater than or equal to" (which is commonly denoted using `$\geq$`: $\geq$) or as an arrow (which is commonly denoted using `$\Rightarrow$`: $\Rightarrow$)?

Comment: There’s a unit problem somewhere.  The downwash does not have units of force so why should the downwash be $1kg/s$?  Why not $1kg$ per millisecond or per minute?

Answer (score 2):

An object's weight is the force exerted on the object by gravity.  That force is equal to the object's mass times the strength of the gravitational field, which is acceleration.

(That acceleration is the same for all objects in the gravitational field at the same point).

A lot of people confuse weight and mass, because weight is proportional to mass.  But if the gravitational field strength changes (e.g., it is slightly different at the top of a mountain than at the bottom of a deep valley), the weight changes although the mass does not change.

Lift is the upward force exerted by wings, rotors, buoyancy, etc.  In order to hover or stay at a fixed height, an aircraft's lift must balance the aircraft's *weight*.  So, (hover lift) = weight = mass x g.

Comment: I'm not confusing mass and weight.  ‘Lift = Mass’ is not meant to imply that 1 N = 1 kg.  Just to be clear, ‘Lift = Mass’ is just trying to emphasize that lift is focused on the force required to circulate (displace) a mass of air each second, (and not weight of air). e.g. A downward force of 1 N is sufficient to circulate (displace) 1 kg/s of air in TOTAL; This is done by the rotors DIRECTLY accelerating a smaller mass of air downwards; which will then INDIRECTLY displace more air. The total mass of air displaced equals: the air directly and indirectly displaced.

Comment: I gave my answer and I'm stickin' to it.

Comment: You missed the point that gravity is a universal constant, so if Lift Weight; then Lift = Mass, as gravity cancels out.

Comment: OK, your confusion is between $G$ (the gravitational constant) and $g$ (the acceleration of gravity).  $$F =m_1 \times g = \frac{ G \times m_1 m_2}{d^2}$$ where d is the distance between the two masses.  So $$ g = \frac{ G \times m_1 m_2}{d^2}$$.

Comment: If you can find those words in a textbook, it will be a miracle akin to a roomful of monkeys typing out the works of Shakespeare.

Comment: S. Mc Grew's answer is right. Live with it, PLEASE!!

Comment: 'LIFT = Mass' means:  'Lift  = The force required to push the mass of airplane up (not its weight).'

Comment: The force required to support an object against gravity *is* the object's weight.

Comment: Agreed. But there's not one experiment that show's that Lift = Weight for an airplane in stable flight.